Git corrupted? `reword` of `git rebase -i` suddenly stopped working
TL;DR
I had been using reword instruction of git rebase -i with no problem for a few years.
However, it no longer works only in one of my local Git repositories.
Strangely, just forking the repository locally resolves the problem.
How to Reproduce

Confirms no rebase is in progress and the working directory is clean.
$ git status
On branch x
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git rebase --abort
fatal: no rebase in progress


Starts an interactive rebase.
$ git rebase -i develop


Edits the changelist.
pick 0a280af1 commit_1
pick 4c37991e commit_2
- pick 09191dca commit_3
+ reword 09191dca commit_3
pick cb098966 commit_4
pick 670ce5d9 commit_5


Edits the commit message when prompted.

reword itself succeeds but the pick right after that fails for unknown reason.

commit_4_{a|b}.txt in the error message are already tracked and commit_4 edits them.

The other commits (i.e. commit_{1|2|3|5}) don't touch them.

As confirmed in the step 1 above, the working directory was clean (no local change) at the time of starting git rebase -i.


[detached HEAD 79925137] new_commit_3
 Date: Mon Sep 2 15:55:29 2024 +0900
 2 files changed, 185 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 commit_3_a.txt
 create mode 100644 commit_3_b.txt
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    commit_4_a.txt
    commit_4_b.txt
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
hint: Could not execute the todo command
hint:
hint:     pick cb0989660941c763e6935d63105205e296a2c11f commit_4
hint:
hint: It has been rescheduled; To edit the command before continuing, please
hint: edit the todo list first:
hint:
hint:     git rebase --edit-todo
hint:     git rebase --continue



Workaround
I have a strange workaround.

Locally forks the repository.
$ cd /path/to/new_directory
$ git clone /path/to/original_project


Executes exactly the same steps shown in How to Reproduce section above.

It works like a charm.


Environment

macOS Sonoma (M3 Apple Silicon)

Git 2.46.0 (installed via Homebrew)


Question
How can I debug the problem?

I think the message is very clear about what is going on. Were commit_4_a.txt and commit_4_b.txt ignored/untracked? It looks like you have changes on those files that are not committed locally and so git is warning you about that so that you do not lose them because the commit that is being picked there (cb0989660941) has changes for them (check git show --name-status --pretty="" cb0989660941).

@eftshift0 (Q1) Were commit_4_a.txt and commit_4_b.txt ignored/untracked? (A1) They are already tracked and commit_4 edits them. The other commits (i.e. commit_1, ..., commit_5 except for commit_4) don't touch them. (Q2) It looks like you have changes on those files that are not committed locally (A2) As shown in the OP, I checked the working directory was completely clean via git status. Isn't that enough? At which timing (or phase, or step) should I execute git show --name-status --pretty=""?

So, if you run git status it is clean right now, if I understand correctly. Have you used git update-index --assume-unchanged with those 2 files, by any chance?

@eftshift0 (Q1) So, if you run git status it is clean right now (A1) Yes. It's clean. (Q2) Have you used git update-index --assume-unchanged (A2) No. I didn't even know update-index command. (Q3) you should not do pick and reword as 2 separate operations... (A3) I'm sorrry. The way I wrote the step was ambiguous. I showed the change in so-called diff style. I actually replaced pick with reword.

and I got it after taking a closer look at what you did, that's why I removed the comment about that.

Ok, that status that you have there... is that status before starting the rebase? Cause I would like to see what status is when rebase fails at that commit that you are rewording.

@eftshift0 The working directories before starting the rebase and just after the failure are both clean. (The former is shown in the OP. The latter is not shown in the OP but I just checked it now.)

Perhaps running git with GIT_TRACE=1 might give us some info?

Sounds like you have problems with a case-insensitive filesystem or with non-ASCII file names.

@eftshift0 I compared the outputs of GIT_TRACE=1 git rebase -i develop executed in the problematic repository and in the non problematic local fork. The difference was I only initialized a Git submodule in the former repository. So I tried git submodule deinit and it resolved the problem though the series of commits are completely irrelevant to the submodule. Re-executing git submodule init revives the problem. I also tried git gc, git fsck to no avail. Executing git submodule init in the fork did NOT expose the problem. I'm giving up now... Thank you for many advises!

@j6t The filenames are ASCII. I'm using case-insensitive filesystem as I'm on macOS. However, they should not matter because, as shown in the OP, just cloning the exact same repository locally resolves the problem. As I just wrote in this comment, I'm giving up now... It's too time-consuming to debug this weird problem. I will use the fork; both have exactly the same contents.

TL;DR
The cache of a Git submodule (i.e. .git/modules) was corrupted. Just removing the directory and re-initializing the submodule resolved the problem.
I don't know why, though.

As written in this comment, I compared the output of GIT_TRACE=1 git rebase -i develop executed in the original problematic project and the one executed in a non problematic local fork to find that I initialized a Git submodule only in the former case.
So I tried these steps:

I executed git submodule deinit <directory name> to de-initialize the submodule in the former repository. After that, reword started to work with no problem.

That said, I do need the submodule. So I again executed git submodule init. This made reword fail again.

Then, in the non problematic fork, I executed git submodule init. Still reword was working.


This debugging implies the cache of the submodule (i.e. .git/modules) in the former repository was corrupted (though git gc and git fsck didn't work).
It should not matter because the series of the commits being rebased are completely irrelevant to and independent of the submodule's contents. But anyway I tried:

git submodule deinit <directory name>

mv .git/modules/ .git/modules.bak (removes the submodule cache)

git submodule init

git submodule update


Now reword is working again.

When I got this warning.
hint: Could not execute the todo command
hint: 
hint:     pick 7a28843143d06703829d7b19106934b2fb9ec58b Add my short conscience commit message
hint: 
hint: It has been rescheduled; To edit the command before continuing, please
hint: edit the todo list first:
hint: 
hint:     git rebase --edit-todo
hint:     git rebase --continue

My solution was to remove the lock file, eg:
rm .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG.lock

I got exactly same error message after pulling a feature branch created by my Linux colleague while trying to rebase and squash its commits.
The root of problem was that the branch contained a commit of new file with space mistakenly added at the end of filename. Although the subsequent commit repaired that mistake, the git rebase command in my Git for Windows refused to deal with that commit. None advice of those above worked nor could I emulate error in my environment (touch "x.txt " ; git add "x.txt " fails). The corrupted commit was also unable to fixup with previous commit.
The solution was to download newly added file from Gitlab web GUI and edit the last healthy commit such that the file is amended to it. Then drop both the corrupted and renaming commit.
Suppose this state before:
1f943614      grandparent
7b620d59      parent
2759ce46      commit of 'filename.yaml '
356f7617      rename 'filename.yaml ' to 'filename.yaml'
db537dc3 HEAD remaining changes

Then the git rebase -i 1f943614 with following todo list applies:
e 7b620d5 parent
d 2759ce4 commit of 'filename.yaml '
d 356f761 rename 'filename.yaml ' to 'filename.yaml'
pick db537dc3 remaining changes

This rebase was with no problems finally hence force push of repaired branch may follow.
